# Why does std::unordered_map not work with const std::string key?

Tags: c++, unordered-map

The following code example will not compile, however it can be made to compile by removing the `const` specifier before `std::string` as the unordered map key.

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <utility>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

    int myint = 5;
    std::unordered_map<const std::string, int*> map;
    map.insert({"string", &myint});
    std::cout << *map.at("string") << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Why does this code not compile when `const std::string` is used as a key, when `std::string` works?

Comment: @NO_NAME wrong duplicate

Comment: What's the point of this? The key in the map is a copy of the original string.

Comment: @Barmar To be explicit?

Comment: I would like to know why `map` and `unordered_map` differ in this regard.  It's a shame the duplicate doesn't seem to address this question.

Comment: @SergeyA Why? It refers to the exactly the same problem.

Comment: It seems to be a strange inconsistency in the standard library

Comment: @NO_NAME because it doesn't answer the question asked: WHY does it not compile

Comment: @Barmar I still maintain it is not a duplicate. It does not answer the question *why it doesn't compile*, while this question has an answer together with a possible workaround.

Comment: Strings are values, at least in this context.

Answer (score 4):

`std::unordered_map` uses `std::hash` by default for the hash function.  It uses the type of the key for the template type of `std::hash`.  `<string>` specializes `std::hash` for `std::string` but since the key type is `const std::string`, there is no matching specialization and compilation fails.

---

Really though, using `std::unordered_map<std::string, int*>` will do exactly what you need.  The key in all associative containers is `const` already for you so there is no reason to mark in `const` in the template parameters.

Comment: Is this a "bug"?

Comment: @user3728501 in where?

Comment: The standard library. I might want my keys to be const?

Comment: @user3728501 It's not a code bug.  You might call it a language bug (the standard should say there needs to be a const version) but since keys in associative containers are made const it's not really needed.  `std::unordered_map<std::string, int*>` will do the exact same thing and actually compile.

Comment: Sure that's what I mean - a language bug

Comment: @user3728501 language bugs are normally called defects in standard. While it might be a defect, it is a minor one - you can easily workaround it by providing your own `hash` for `const`. On the other hand, having key as a const type solves nothing.

Comment: @SergeyA Why would every developer in the world who wished to put the const specifier there also implement their own hash function?

Comment: Every developer in the world could think about 'why' they want to do it, and find out there is no good reason for it?

Comment: @user3728501 I would post that on isocpp.org. looks like a proposal.